# Q: How do I obtain an authentication code while avoiding redirects

Tags: asp.net, redirect, facebook-c#-sdk

I've been trying to face this issue for a couple of days now.

The whole facebook sdk procedure is pretty simple but there's one tough nut to crack.

My problem is redirecting properly back to my website with the auth code.

I've been running into numerous problems trying to redirect back to the site after redirecting to facebook oAuth page and I want to see if there's anyway I can work around it. (e.g. not redirect but rather open a popup with facebook login, and have it return the auth code via ajax or what not)

I am hesitant between trying to come up with a way around using the redirect method or trying to somehow solve it.

TL;DR: I want to open a new facebook auth window and somehow get the auth code returning from it once the user authenticates.

Any clues?

```
             if (Request["code"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect(string.Format(
                    "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}",
                    app_id, redirectUri, scope) + "'", true);
            }
```